# How to run featurePlot from script in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret

I have loaded some training set and would like to apply [`featurePlot`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/featurePlot) to it.

If I do it directly from console in `RStudio`, it works ok -- some plot appears in plot pane of `RStudio`.

Although it looks like it works asynchronously.

If I wish to run it from script, I fail:

```
library(ISLR); library(ggplot2); library(caret);
data(Wage)
training<-Wage;

##filename <- sprintf("images/wage%%03d.png")

##png(filename)

featurePlot(x=training[,c("age","education","jobclass")],
            y = training$wage,
            plot="pairs")

##dev.off()
```

No any plots appear and if writing to file uncommented, then empty files appear.

How to run `featurePlot` from script then? Probably I should wait it finished somehow?

Comment: Sorry didn't knew they don't give to unsigned. Here is the description: http://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/data  It is a table with 95 columns, 1st colum is "id" of integer, 93 columns are "feat_%d" of numeric, and last column is "target" of factors. There 61000+ rows in a table.

Comment: @Pascal look now; have changed data source in example code.

Comment: I get a figure with 4x4 plots. What is your script?

Comment: My script is entirely above. I also get figure with 4.x 4 plots if run from command line. But get nothing if write to file "try02.R" and then do `source("try02.R")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to store the the plot in an object `obj`, then print this object `print(obj)`, as `featurePlot` is shortcut to produce `lattice` graphs. You can try:

```
library(ISLR)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
data(Wage)
training <- Wage

filename <- sprintf("images/wage%%03d.png")

obj <- featurePlot(x=training[,c("age","education","jobclass")],
                   y = training$wage,
                   plot="pairs")

png(filename)
print(obj)
dev.off()
```